# How to get the first 40 characters of a NSString in a line

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablestring

I have a NSString. I am trying to take the first 40 characters of the first line. 
As of now, I have done this.

```
NSString *text = @"Somewhere, something incredible is waiting to be known";
text = [text substringToIndex:40];

NSLog(OUTPUT : %@, text); 
OUTPUT : Somewhere, something incredible is wait
```

the string `waiting` is not completed. The actual output I required is

```
REQ OUTPUT : Somewhere, something incredible is waiting
```

I need the first 40 characters but if the last word is incomplete, it should be completed.
Can some one tell me how to do this?.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is because even blank spaces are counted as characters

Comment: How do I know whether the last word is incomplete?

Comment: what you have tried so far? can you post please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code

```
 NSString *text = @"Somewhere, something incredible is waiting to be known";
__block NSInteger targetIndex = text.length;
[text enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, text.length)
                           options:NSStringEnumerationByWords
                        usingBlock:
 ^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
     NSInteger lastIndex = substringRange.location + substring.length;
     if (lastIndex > 40) {
         targetIndex = lastIndex;
         *stop = true;
     }
 }];
text = [text substringToIndex:targetIndex];
NSLog(@"%@",text);
```

Log

> Somewhere, something incredible is waiting

Answer (score 1):

Logic to check if last word is incomplete.

1. Get the 41st character and check if it is spaces.
2. If yes, then do nothing.
3. Else, get the position of the last space in your string (trimmed string) and trim your parent string till that position.

if you can extend more than 40 characters to complete your string, then you check for the first space after 40th character and trim your parent string till that position.

Hope you would be able to convert it into Obj-C